# Capturing the correct groups

Tags: regex

I have trouble parsing optional `?` quantifiers when dealing with space  character, the optional text cannot be correctly parsed after `(.+)`.

[Examples](https://regex101.com/r/Ss9IKB/1): The user can only use these input: "what ", "what  is/are", "i want to know/love to know what  is/are". I came up with an incorrect regex `(?:i )?(?:want to know |love to know )?what (.+)(?: is| are)?`. In the captures bellow, I need the desired example results: `big house` and `big houses`.

- Correct captures:

  ```
  what big house
  ```
- Incorrect captures:

  ```
  what big house is

  love to know what big houses are

  i want to know what big house is
  ```

Comment: if you want `big house` or `big houses` why are you searching for 'love to know' or 'want to know' or 'is' or 'are' in your regex?

Comment: your requirement and the regex you have written are kinda not matching. explain what your regex is doing. especially why are you checking for `want to know |love to know ` and say it is not a match???

Comment: @AbdulHameed In my regex, they got the wrong grouped values: `big house is` and `big houses are` like in the example link.

Comment: @NaguibIhab I meant to capture `big house` in `i want to know what big house is` right, but failed to make a correct regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following *regex* should do the job :

```
(?m)(?<=what\s).*?(?=\s(?:is|are|$))
```

see **[demo / explanation](https://regex101.com/r/pJD5qi/3)**

Comment: Your regex didn't match the first case `what big house` though.

Comment: The desired results I want are `big house` and `big houses` in the examples though. Your 1st version doesn't capture the value correctly.

Comment: @MiP oh.. my bad, I misunderstood. check the updated answer now. it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> I need the desired results: big house and big houses.

Then the regex you're after is `big house[s]?`

Comment: I meant the desired results in the examples.